# Viewpager Do not destroy / Save destroyed page

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I have viewpager and asynctask together. I'm showing content without problem.

But;  When I add radio buttons to pages ( for multiple choice questions ), after I swipe between contents, previous checked choices go  unchecked. I want to save this checked choices

PagerAdapter:

```
public class QuestionPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    public QuestionPagerAdapter(){
        super();

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int qcount = QuestionPagerAdapter.q.getQuestionCount();
        return qcount;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int pos) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //View v = null;
        Context mycontext = collection.getContext();
        View page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_quiz, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView)page.findViewById(R.id.questionText);

            FetchTask fft = new FetchTask(tv);
        fft.execute(pos);

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(page, 0);
        return page;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
        //Util.Log("destroying" + position);
        ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
    }

}
```

AsyncTask:

```
public  class FetchTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, ArrayList<String>>  {

        TextView outTxt;

        public FetchTask(TextView outputTxt, LinearLayout linlay, RadioGroup mrg, Context dcontext) {

                outTxt = outputTxt;             

                } 

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Integer... uri) {

            ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

                result.add(uri[0] + " " );

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            outTxt.setText(result.get(0));

        }

    }
```

Comment: You can save the checked states in some static variables. Static variables will not get cleared until app is closed.

Comment: Shrikant idea is valid, but this is not the android way of managing creation en destruction of fragments/activities. If you handle these correctly you will not have this problem. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html